# Varience of $Y^2$ given Variance of $Y$

Tags: statistics

During an eight-hour shift, the proportion of time $y$ that a sheer-metal stamping machine is down for maintenance or repairs has a Beta distribution with $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=2$. That is,

f(y) =
\begin{cases}
2(1-y),  & 0 \le y \le 1 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}

The cost(in hundreds of dollars) of this downtime, due to lost production and cost of maintenance and repair, is given by $C=10+20Y+4Y^2$. Find the mean and variance of $C$.

---

$E[Y]=\int ^1_0(2y-2y^2)$ $dy=\frac{1}{3}$

$E[Y^2]=\int^1_0(2y^2-2y^3)$ $dy=\frac{1}{6}$

$Var(Y)=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{18}$

So, we have

$E[C]=E[10]+20E[Y]+4E[Y^2]=17\frac{1}{3}$

$Var(Y)=0+400Var(Y)+16Var(Y^2)$

I am required to compute $Var(Y^2)$.

I proceeded by

f(y^2) =
\begin{cases}
4(1-y)^2,  & 0 \le y \le 1 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}

$E[Y^4]=\int ^1_0 4y^2(1-y)^2$ $dy=\frac{4}{30}$

$Var(Y^2)=\frac{4}{30}-(\frac{1}{6}))^2=\frac{19}{180}$

Then I substitute. Is it correct for $var(Y^2)$?

Comment: Sorry but $C=10+20Y+4Y^2$ does not imply $Var(C)=0+400Var(Y)+16Var(Y^2)$, not by far. Please go back to the definitions.

Comment: Actually I now see there are several similar basic blunders in your post, for example your computation of $E(Y^4)$ is just... bizarre, so imagining a helpful answer is difficult.

Comment: Well I know that the variance part has been blundered. That is why I posted it as a question. Had I got the answer, I would not have posted it, isn"t it? You could please give some hints on the question, what I mean is the initial lines to be written to calculate the variance.

Comment: Starting from $E(Y^n)=\frac2{(n+1)(n+2)}$ from every nonnegative $n$ and from $C=10+4X$ with $X=Y^2+5Y$, can you compute $E(X^2)$?

Comment: That is quite helpful. Thank you

Comment: Can someone explain why C=10+20Y+4$Y^2$ does not imply Var(C)=400Var(Y)+16Var($Y^2$). I am referring to the first comment above

Answer (score -1):

I also struggled for this question for a while today and I would like to archive my solution:

First,$\operatorname{Var}(C) ≠ 0+400\operatorname{Var}()+16\operatorname{Var}(^2)$ because $\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Y^2)$ is not zero. (please look for other reference if you are confused about what is covariance)

The right way to calculate V(C) is
$V(C)=E(C^2)-(E(C))^2=(100+400E(Y)+480E(Y^2)+160E(Y^3)+16E(Y^4))-(E(C))^2$