# Probability - Variance of the square of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

I was looking at the problem under the link below (did not want to post the same problem twice) and I got confused by one of the comments.
We have a random variable $X$ and then we have $C$ = $10$ + $20X$ + $4X^2$.

The first comment under says that $C$ = $10$ + $20X$ + $4X^2$ does not imply that $Var(C)$ = $400Var(X)$ + $16Var(X^2)$.

I am wondering what I am missing here since I did it the same way.

[Varience of $Y^2$ given Variance of $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1960765/902140)